# Error when running Pytest with Delta Lake Tables

Tags: unit-testing, apache-spark, pyspark, pytest, delta-lake

I am working in the VDI of a company and they use their own artifactory for security reasons.
Currently I am writing unit tests to perform tests for a function that deletes entries from a delta table. When I started, I received an error of unresolved dependencies, because my spark session was configured in a way that it would load jars from maven. I was able to solve this issue by loading these jars locally from /opt/spark/jars. Now my code looks like this:

```
class TestTransformation(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def test_ksu_deletion(self):
        self.spark = SparkSession.builder\
                        .appName('SPARK_DELETION')\
                        .config("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore")\
                        .config("spark.jars", "/opt/spark/jars/delta-core_2.12-0.7.0.jar, /opt/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar")\
                        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")\
                        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")\
                        .getOrCreate()
        os.environ["KSU_DELETION_OBJECT"]="UNITTEST/"
        deltatable = DeltaTable.forPath(self.spark, "/projects/some/path/snappy.parquet")
        deltatable.delete(col("DATE") < get_current()
```

However, I am getting the error message:

```
E     py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.forPath.
E     : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;)V
```

Do you have any idea by what this is caused? I am assuming it has to do with the way I am configuring spark.sql.extions and/or the spark.sql.catalog, but to be honest, I am quite a newb in Spark.
I would greatly appreciate any hint.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit:
We are using Spark 3.0.2 (Scala 2.12.10). According to https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html, this should be compatible. Apart from the SparkSession, I trimmed down the subsequent code to

```
df.spark.read.parquet(Path/to/file.snappy.parquet)
```

and now I am getting the error message

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.DeltaDelete has interface org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.UnaryNode as super class
```

As I said, I am quite new to (Py)Spark, so please dont hesitate to mention things you consider completely obvious.

Edit 2: I checked the Python path I am exporting in the Shell before running the code and I can see the following:
[image]
Could this cause any problem? I dont understand why I do not get this error when running the code within pipenv (with spark-submit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you're using incompatible version of the Delta lake library. 0.7.0 was for Spark 3.0, but you're using another version - either lower, or higher. Consult [Delta releases page](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html) to find mapping between Delta version & required Spark versions.

If you're using Spark 3.1 or 3.2, consider using [delta-spark](https://pypi.org/project/delta-spark/) Python package that will install all necessary dependencies, so you just import `DeltaTable` class.

Update: Yes, this happens because of the conflicting versions - you need to remove `delta-spark` and `pyspark` Python package, and install `pyspark==3.0.2` explicitly.

P.S. Also, look onto [pytest-spark](https://github.com/malexer/pytest-spark) package that can simplify specification of configuration for all tests.  You can find examples of it + Delta [here](https://github.com/alexott/spark-playground/tree/master/testing).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Alex. I edited my original post, maybe you can have look if you have some spare time

Comment: I see `delta-spark` version 1.1.0 installed in your Python environment, so it may conflict with your Spark version. If you want to stay on 3.0.2, then you need uninstall that version, and use import DeltaTable like this: https://github.com/alexott/spark-playground/blob/a52c41f098e2f3729c996977769b34acc41cf4c4/testing/src/python/test-delta.py